# Convert CSV containing values for each dates to JSON

Tags: python

I have below csv example:

```
31 Jan 2023,,,,,
Type,Time,Number,Duration,Quantity,Cost
Talk,12:32,61407228499,00:00:14,N/A,$0.00
Talk,11:50,61425380005,00:41:17,N/A,$0.00
Talk,08:28,61414464256,00:20:22,N/A,$0.00
30 Jan 2023,,,,,
Type,Time,Number,Duration,Quantity,Cost
Text,12:24,61431655867,N/A,N/A,$0.00
Talk,11:15,61431655867,00:00:21,N/A,$0.00
Talk,09:00,131318,00:11:53,N/A,$0.00
28 Jan 2023,,,,,
Type,Time,Number,Duration,Quantity,Cost
Talk,12:45,61414464256,00:00:03,N/A,$0.00
27 Jan 2023,,,,,
```

I want to have something like below using Python:

```json
{
 "31 Jan 2023":{
        "Type": "Talk",
        "Time": "12:32",
        "Number: "61407228499",
        "Duration: "00:00:14",
        "Quantity": "N/A",
        "Cost": "$0.00"
     },
 "30 Jan 2023":{
        "Type": "Talk",
        "Time": "12:32",
        "Number: "61407228499",
        "Duration: "00:00:14",
        "Quantity": "N/A",
        "Cost": "$0.00"
     },
  
.. and so on..

}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What is the problem ?

Comment: as the dates are also in a row mixed in csv, how can I get those dates and assign it as keys, then assign the succeeding values to the dates?

Comment: That's not a CSV to begin with. CSV doesn't mean random text with commas. Dates in JSON *must* be in ISO8601 format, not localized formats

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit strange csv file format, so we have to do tricky work

First of all, we have to read df and separate rows by date

```
def is_date(s: str):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(s, "%d %b %Y")
    except:
        return False
    return True

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)
df["is_date"] = df[df.columns[0]].apply(is_date)
```

Now we can have index of dates

```
ind = df[df.is_date].index
```

And now we can get date referenced information in loop

```
def date_df(df: pd.DataFrame):
    try:
        r = df.iloc[1:, 0:6]
        # make first row header
        r.columns = r.iloc[0]
        r = r[1:]
        r = r.transpose()
        return json.loads(r.to_json())
    except IndexError:
        return {}

d = {}
for i_0, i_1 in zip(ind[0:-1], ind[1:]):
    # data of specified date
    data = df.iloc[i_0:i_1, :]
    date = data.iloc[0][0]
    json_data = date_df(data)
    d[date] = list()
    for v in json_data.values():
        d[date].append(v)
```

And don't forget about last date

```
i_0 = ind[-1]
data = df.iloc[i_0:, :]
date = data.iloc[0][0]
js_data = date_df(data)
d[date] = list()
for v in js_data.values():
    d[date].append(v)
```

Variable d is something like:

```
{
  "31 Jan 2023": [
    {
      "Type": "Talk",
      "Time": "12:32",
      "Number": "61407228499",
      "Duration": "00:00:14",
      "Quantity": null,
      "Cost": "$0.00"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Talk",
      "Time": "11:50",
      "Number": "61425380005",
      "Duration": "00:41:17",
      "Quantity": null,
      "Cost": "$0.00"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Talk",
      "Time": "08:28",
      "Number": "61414464256",
      "Duration": "00:20:22",
      "Quantity": null,
      "Cost": "$0.00"
    }
  ],
  "30 Jan 2023": [
    {
      "Type": "Text",
      "Time": "12:24",
      "Number": "61431655867",
      "Duration": null,
      "Quantity": null,
      "Cost": "$0.00"
    },
...
```

Comment: It's not CSV at all. It almost looks like someone exported multi-line records to Excel then saved that as CSV.